# How to get refresh token of the main user account in SynapsePay?

Tags: payment-gateway, synapsepay

I have a main admin account in SynapsePay, under which I can add `n` number of users as beneficiaries (and their bank accounts too).

Now I need to transfer money from my admin account to other beneficiary accounts. In order to do that, I need the admin account's "oAuthkey" which can be extracted from admin's "refresh token". I need to know how can I get admin accounts refresh token?

Comment: I don't see any problem with code here, which could make your question off-topic in this site. Are you having a problem with some code to refresh tokens?

Comment: Thank You, Llopis for the reply.I got it sorted out anyway.